# Function returns vector instead of scalar

Tags: matlab, function

I have defined two anonymous functions like this:

```
hx = @(x) 0.23.*(x>=a).*(x<5) + ...
          2.8020.*exp(-x/2).*(x>=5).*(x<=b);

Hx = @(x) p.*c.*x.*(x>=0).*(x<5) + ...
          p.*(5.*c - 2.*d.*(exp(-x/2)-exp(-5/2))).*(x>=5).*(x<=18);
```

both piecewise. The problem is that `hx` when evaluated returns a vector of results. Why is this happening? I can't figure it out. The other function just returns one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're feeding both `hx` and `Hx` with a *scalar*, it seems that `hx` returns a vector because either `a` or `b` (or both) is a vector (as opposed to `c`, `d` and `p`, which are apparently scalars too).

Comment: I'm sure they are scalars all of them. I just closed Matlab and open it and it does not evaluate to a vector !

Comment: Are `a` and `b` defined in the global workspace? If so, perhaps you've mistakenly overrun the scalar value of either `a` or `b` with a vector before defining `hx` (_e.g_ from the command window).

Answer (score 4):

You can try to include a and b to your anonymous function :

```
hx = @(x,a,b) 0.23.*(x>=a).*(x<5) + ...
      2.8020.*exp(-x/2).*(x>=5).*(x<=b);
```